# How can I monitor network requests made by an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, http, eclipse-plugin

We have an in-house Eclipse plugin which we use for deployments. In essence, it is nothing more than a front end to send the names and versions of the projects to deploy to a server, where this data is later used by another group to know which versions of which projects to deploy.

I want to script this process. To do so, I need to know what kinds of network requests the plugin does when I click the buttons on the plugin.

So, is there way to monitor the network requests made by an Eclipse plugin?

Comment: If this is an in-house plug-in, why not talk to its developers?

Comment: @nitind That might be possible but if possible, learning how to monitor a plugin would be great as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any built-in capability to monitor and/or log network activity in the Eclipse platform. But I'd say a general-purpose tool such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (and others) would do a good enough job.